# How to retrieve all results (more than 100) using batch on gmail

Tags: java, gmail, batch-processing

I am using Gmail API with the java client library.
I want to batch a bulk of queries to get a list of messages.
I make a test for only one query.
Here is the snippet of the code :

```
    Gmail client = getClient();     
    BatchRequest batch = client.batch();
    // Create the callback.
    JsonBatchCallback<ListMessagesResponse> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<ListMessagesResponse>() {
        public void onSuccess(ListMessagesResponse listMessagesResponse, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
            System.out.println(listMessagesResponse.getMessages().size());
            System.out.println(listMessagesResponse.getNextPageToken());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    client.users().messages().list("me@gmail.com").queue(batch, callback);      
    batch.execute();
```

The problem is that it retrieves only 100 messages.  I don't want to get the last token and reuse it for the next query, it does not make a sense since I want to use batch.
So How is it posssible to bypass the limitation (100) in order to retrieve all messages in one batch request ?

Thanks